# Как поставить иконку на ползунком

Tags: javascript

Есть ползунок input range со значениями от 1 до 100 нужно там где будет 60 и 80 изначально поставить над ним иконочки не при измененнии а с начала, кто нибудь знает как это сделать?
Сделал на Codepen для наглядности

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/Misha11/pen/zMYPLy?editors=1111">Codepen </a>
```

по сути нужно чтобы лейблы были ровно над выбранным значением одинааково но сейчас первый норм остальные нет

Comment: Приведите пример кода, пожалуйста.

Comment: Определи значение `input`, `input.value` и потом пропиши в функции условия, если  `if(input.value==60)` то запусти функцию которая будет отвечать за появление картинки. А как ты ее будешь скрывать тебе решать, создаваться элемент посредством `js`, или скрывать с помощью `opacity или display: none;` , а может будет подгружаться с помощью `ajax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<img src="1.ico" style="position: absolute; left: 172px" />
<img src="1.ico" style="position: absolute; left: 232px" />
<input type=range style="width: 300px; margin-top: 30px" /><br>
```

Абсолютно позиционируем иконки и задаём позицию по иксу (координату) с рассчёта, допустим, если ширина range равна **300**, то **X** первой иконки будет **60 / 100 * 300 - 8**, где 8, допустим половина ширины иконки, получается **172px**. Во втором случае - соответственно **232px**.

Comment: я сделал как вы подсказали но в трех примерно поставленных лейблах не равномерно, в первом ок в отсальных сдвигается, не знаете как это решить?

Comment: А как ставите лейблы, если мышью и берёте координату x  мыши, то могут быть неувязки, связанные с возможными отступами по горизонтали.

Comment: там нет координат мышки

Comment: https://codepen.io/Misha11/pen/zMYPLy?editors=1111

Comment: Учитывая ширину ползунка и то, что минимальное значение выбора не 0, а 1, перепишите 7 строку JS-кода так: **var left = labels[i] / (el['max'] - el['min']) * (w - 30);**, где 30 - ширина ползунка.

Comment: Спасибо Боьшое!